# JQuery Replacewith DIV does not load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I have login page and I am trying to replace the login form with the signup form if they click the button to sign up.

Currently I have:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("w").replaceWith(function(n){
            return "DIV HERE BUT DIVS DO NOT WORK";
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 social-login">
                        <a href="#" class="google_button login_btn">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-google-plus-square"></i><span>Continue with Google</span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="facebook_button login_btn">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i><span>Continue with Facebook</span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="twitter_button login_btn">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i><span>Continue with Twitter</span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="linkedin_button login_btn">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i><span>Continue with Linkedin</span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="/signup" class="email_button login_btn">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i><span>Continue with Email</span>
                    </a>
                    <button>Continue With Email</button> <span class="light_grey">By signing up you indicate that you have read and agree to the <a target="_blank" href="#">Terms of Service</a> and <a target="_blank" href="#">Privacy Policy</a>.</span>
                </div>

                    <form action="" class="signin_form" method="post">
                        <w><div class="title">Login</div></p></w>
                        <div class="form_inputs">
                            <div class="form_column">
                                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Email" value="" class="username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form_column">
                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" value="" class="password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form_column">
                                <span><div class="remember_checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="" name="remember_checkbox" checked="checked" class="remember_checkbox">Remember Me</div></span><input type="submit" value="Sign In" name="send" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
                                <span><a href="#" class="forgot_password">Forgot Password?</a></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
</body>
```

I would like to replace the form class signin_form with:

```
                        <form action="" class="signup_form" method="post">
                        <div class="title">Sign up!</div>
                        <div class="form_inputs">
                            <div class="form_column">
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $dd; ?>" class="email" placeholder="Email">

                            </div>

                            <div class="form_column">
                                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form_column">
                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" value="" class="password">

                            <div class="form_column">
                                <input type="password" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" value="" class="confirm_password">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form_column">
                                <span><a href="/login" class="forgot_password">Already Have an Account?</a></span><input type="submit" value="Sign Up" name="send" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Using the replaceWith that I am currently using I can replace a single line if it doesn't include a div, if I put in a div it doesn't load anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think replaceWith is not the right way to achieve the functionality that you want, this is not because you cannot, it is because you will then need to dynamically create a new form and have to hook all the events to the elements in the new form.
Instead you should do the following

1. Create both the Signin and Signup form
2. Hide the Signup form in CSS and show only the Signin form
3. On click of the button Hide the Signin form and show the signup form.

This will be the easiest and safest way to achieve the sort of functionality you are after.

Comment: Is there any documentation on how this is done somewhere?

Comment: you mean my answer? Let me quickly write a snippet for you.

Comment: any documentation !!! It's not mean your answer ... Official documentation or others docu..

Comment: I am afraid there won't be any documentation to say that replaceWith cannot be used for your specific needs. But basically any new DOM elements you create on the fly, which is what replaceWith does will not have any events associated with it by default you will need to bind the events yourself and it being a FORM it makes it more error prone. If that makes sense.

Comment: David I have no idea what your trying to say. Anyways Senthil thank you for the suggestion, I have gone ahead and done that using the .show and .hide as i found in the jquery documentation but its still fighting me, anyway you could take a look maybe point me in the right direction. https://jsfiddle.net/upcbq0xe/

Comment: @DustinSnider that is good. If my answer helped you, then please select it as your answer.

Comment: You commented back while I was editing my comment. I'll select it as correct but anyway I might be able to get a little bit more push in the right direction. Its still fighting me. jsfiddle.net/upcbq0xe